# Time-Series analysis in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have data for countries in Southeast Asia which looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcj5I.jpg)

The list goes on for Cambodia, Indonesia, Laos etc.

I am planning to conduct a regression analysis with HDI as the independent variable and GTD (Number of terrorist incidents) as the dependent variable. However, from my understanding, conducting an OLS regression would only account for one year?

How could I go about conducting a time-series analysis and subsequent regression using all the years (1996-2017) with the country data? I hope to seek some clarification on this. Thank you :)

Comment: Interesting data set. OLS on time series is a pretty reliable way to draw the wrong conclusions. Time series analysis would examine whether this year's results depend on the e.g. HDI as well as the previous year's results. There are a lot of resources on R and Time Series Analysis. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a question more suited to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ (as @Jason pointed out in his comment there are some dangers). In short you would be using all the years because what you are asking in a simple regression is 'how much does one variable depend on another'. In your case you would be using all your data HDI and GTD, they just happen to be spread over many years.

Simple example:

```
library(gapminder) #if you do not have these packages then install.packages("gapminder"), install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

head(gapminder) #first 6 rows of the data
plot(gapminder$lifeExp, gapminder$gdpPercap) #Probably not a linear relationship but let's go on anyway for demonstration purposes
fit <- lm(lifeExp ~ gdpPercap, data = gapminder) #Simple regression using all data from all countries for all years
summary(fit)
plot(fit)
```

Ideally you will want to do a full exploration (is linear regression certainly appropriate?) including the distribution of residuals and experiment with subsetting by country so I recommend reading up on some of the many resources on how to do simple regression.

P.S. Ignore the poor realism of the simple example, that would in reality be a very poor use of linear regression!

Comment: Definitely a question more for https://stats.stackexchange.com/ .